# Microsoft Word scroll bar - change thumb size or use two thumbs

Tags: ms-word, scrollbar

I am using scroll bars to position activities against a range of criteria - for visual presentation.

One scroll bar needs to show a range - ideally I'd have two thumbs, with one at the minimum end of the range and one at the maximum. However, I think that is not possible with Microsoft Word.

Alternatively, it would work to change the thumb size so that the thumb covers the full range. I have tried to find online how to do this, but I can't make sense of any of the responses. I am used to using VBA in Excel but have never used Microsoft Word for this sort of thing. Any simple instructions for how to do this would be very appreciated!

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do and how your desired outcome would look like. If it is about modifying the built-in scrollbars of Word: No, you can't modify their look and behavior using VBA.

Comment: Thank you - I'm talking about the ActiveX Control ScrollBar that I can add using the Developer tab - and I'd like to modify the size of the 'thumb'. Is that not possible?